# I am trying an input form in Power BI with python scripts. It is working in my power BI desktop. But when published to workspace,it's showing error

Tags: powerbi-desktop

It is showing :moduleNotfoundError:No module named Tkinter
I have this Tkinter installed in my system , how do I make it work in workspace as well.Th rest of the plots are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have personal gateway. On server you need also to install all python modules.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-gateway-personal-mode

Comment: Thank you. I've installed personal gateway. Now where should I install the python modules ? can u explain? I'm new to PowerBi and I couldn't find any related articles.

Comment: You should install personal gateway on server and at this same server you should install python library/modules.  Also check if you have correctly added python to windows path

https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/